# How can I open a new activity using a button in a fragment?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to move from a fragment to an activity with a button, but every the button is pressed my program crashes. I can't seem to find the source of the error.

I have tried changing the intent statement in many ways but each time the program still crashes, and I'm not being given any details on the error.

```
public class ExercisesFragment extends Fragment {

    int[] newArray;
    
    private FragmentExercisesBinding binding;
    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentExercisesBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), container, false);
        View view = binding.getRoot();
    
        newArray = new int[]{
    
              R.id.barbellRow, R.id.barbellFrontSquat, R.id.barbellShrugs, R.id.bodyweightSquat, R.id.dumbbellChestPress,
                R.id.lateralRaise, R.id.overheadTricepExtensions, R.id.pullUps, R.id.pushUps, R.id.rearDeltFlies,
                R.id.romanianDeadlifts, R.id.seatedDumbbellCurl, R.id.sitUps, R.id.shoulderPress, R.id.standingCurl,
    
    
        };
    
    
        return view;
    }
    
    public void Imagebuttonclicked(View view) {
    
    
        for (int i=0;i< newArray.length;i++){
    
    
            if(view.getId() == newArray[i]) {
               int value = i+1;
               Log.i("FIRST", String.valueOf(value));
               Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),tutorialActivity.class);
               getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    
    
            }
        }
    
    }

}
```

Here is the stacktrace for the error that occurs when I press on the small arrow buttons:

> E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.neafitnessapp, PID: 23372
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method
> Imagebuttonclicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for
> android:onClick attribute defined on view class
> android.widget.LinearLayout with id 'barbellRow'
> at
> android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(View.java:6359)
> at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:6316)
> at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506)
> at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483)
> at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
> at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29334)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the crash?

Answer (score 1):

**Your Problem**

> I have tried changing the intent statement in many ways but each time the program still crashes, and I'm not being given any details on the error.

The crash is telling you the exact problem. This is how to debug your issue:

First, look at the actual exception that was raised and read the information:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method Imagebuttonclicked(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.widget.LinearLayout with id 'barbellRow'

You didn't post your layout but from this very detailed error we know you have a `LinearLayout` with id `barbellRow` on which you set the `android:onClick` attribute to the `Imagebuttonclicked(View)` method.

We also know that problem is that that method was not found "in a parent or ancestor Context". From [the documentation,](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#attr_android:onClick) for `onClick` we know that (emphasis mine):

> For instance, if you specify android:onClick="sayHello", you must declare a public void sayHello(View v) method of your **context (typically, your Activity).**

From your code, your click handler is defined in your `Fragment` and `Fragment` is not a `Context`, so it fails.

**So the solution is one of two options:**

1 - (Preferred) - Don't use the gimmicky `onClick` attribute and set the click listener on the `LinearLayout` explicitly in your `Fragment`. This will be more obvious and keeps your click handling local to your `Fragment` instead of having it being handle by the `Activity`.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = FragmentExercisesBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), container, false);
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    // Your existing code

    // Set onclicklistener explicitly
    binding.barbellRow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Imagebuttonclicked(v);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

2 - If you want to use the `onClick` attribute, move the function to the `Activity` in which the `Fragment` lives to satisfy the conditions required by that attribute.

Comment: How do I go about setting a click listener on the LinearLayout explicitly in my fragment?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: I'm now getting an error message underneath OnClickListener() saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'OnClickListener'. Also there is an error for @Override stating that the 'Method does not override method from its superclass'. And the Method 'onClick(android.view.View)' is never used.

Comment: I've tried to help you and I've answered your original question. I don't have the the time to walk you through every compiler error you encounter. Please make an effort to solve the problem yourself. There are plenty of examples for setting a click listener if you Google, including the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/button#java. If you can't solve the problem, open a new, specific question to get help.